# Error message in terminal on startup

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

As soon as I startup the terminal (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), I get the error message:

```
bash: export: `/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/': not a valid identifier
```

I am not really familiar with Linux yet. How do I rectify this?

**EDIT:**

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion

fi

export PATH=$PATH/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/usr/local/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/sbin$

export PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/usr/local/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/sbin/usr/$

export PATH=$PATH:/home/lib-11/Downloads/randfold-2.0/randfold

export PERL5LIB=PERL5LIB:/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2 /lib/perl5/site_perl/5$

export PATH=$PATH:/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2
```

mirdeep2 and randfold are executables that I wanted to run.

Comment: Hi There! Can you post the output of `export | grep "/lib/perl5"`.

Comment: @AzkerM Yeah I think there is something more serious, it says "Command 'grep' is available in '/bin/grep'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
grep: command not found"

Comment: @AzkerM I have to put "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin" each time I start the terminal to connect to the bin and permanent solutions dont seem to work

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the contents of your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Parto Please check the question. I have edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because of the space in the line `export PERL5LIB=PERL5LIB:/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2 /lib/perl5/site_perl/5$` (Notice the space between mirdeep2 and /lib/perl5)

It should be `export PERL5LIB=PERL5LIB:/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/perl5/site_perl/5$` (Without space)

Comment: That fixed it thanks. But can you please advice me on why I have to put export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin each time I start up

Comment: You might try to check answers in this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up , there are lot of ways to do it, just choose what is working for your script.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already been told the main issue was the space in the variable's definition. However, your `~/.bashrc` file has a few more issues. First of all, it is not the right place to define the `PATH` or `PERL5LIB` variables. These [should instead be added](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3085/22222) to `~/.profile` or, if the file exists, to `~/.bash_profile`.

Also, all of the `export` lines can be combined into these two:

```
export "PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/lib-11/Downloads/randfold-2.0/randfold:/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2"

export PERL5LIB="PERL5LIB:/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/perl5/site_perl/5"
```